# Is it faster to wield light-weight weapons?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

For example, Glass Bows are the best damage inflicting light-weight weapons. Daedric bows do a lot more damage, but they are much heavier. Does it take more time to get a Daedric bow ready to shoot, than it does with a Glass one? Can I do more strikes in a given time period with a Glass greatsword than a Daedric one? I would test this, but I'm only on Lvl 15 so these weapons are hard to come by right now...

EDIT: I forgot to mention. I'm playing Laedon, a wood-elf sneak archer who wears light armor and lives with 0 scruples. Loves to steal, and is okay with killing for money. ;)

Comment: hmm... the weapon speed thing is poorly documented for skyrim, I can't find any sources to back up my claim so I'll delete it for now.  I am *fairly sure* that attack speed is only due to weapon type and perks though.

Comment: I'll test this later if no one answers by the time I get around to it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As far as I've researched (via wiki's) and tested in game, there is no difference, it is more based on the class of weapon (sword / axe / mace ) than the material structure of the weapon in question.

The materials basically give attributes that make the weapon stronger (coupled with your growing skill progression to use that weapon type).

Speed does not change.

For bows, however, there is a slight difference in [draw speed](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Archery) based on the weight.  Lighter weapons will shoot more arrows in the same amount of time.

Comment: go go testing.  I'd just like to add that heavier weapons cost more stamina for power attacks.

Comment: @yx, bows have no power attacks, so I'm assuming it takes more stamina to 'bash' with a bow - and oh, does it take more stamina to zoom in with a heavier bow?

Comment: @adityamenon, I'm level ~43 and I haven't EVEN run out of stamina with a bow (unless I zoom/stop time for a long time). I would just call it a moot point to try to figure out stamina cost, as it will not diminish your attack capability (at least at my level) via quick zoom shots.

Answer (score 4):

I logged and tried this. They both drew at around one second, no real difference other than the damage.

Comment: I wish I could accept more than one answer. Thanks for the succinct reply, I've voted it up.

Comment: bow draw speed is affected by weight (even though the max difference is only ~.5 seconds), so this answer is incorrect

Answer (score 2):

Bows have no difference other than damage and speed of movement swords on the other hand are different as hevy weapons take longer to swing and are more powerful Oh and with a lighter bow you can carry more (obviously)

Comment: so you are saying that bows *do* affect speed of movement? I take it you mean the walking around in-game rather than the draw-speed right?

Comment: Yes that's what i

Answer (score 1):

I tested two different swords (Blad's and Elven) and counted how many power attacks I was able to perform with each swords before my stamina ran off. They have the same damage but Blad's is lighter (Blad's weights 10 and Elven weights 13). I was able to swing my elven sword 9 times before my stamina was empty. With the Blad's I was barely able to swing 10 times. My stamina is a bit over 300 and I would say that the difference between the two swords is so small that is doesn't matter.

Though I read somewhere on the wiki that the weight is used to absorb attacks when blocking with the weapon. The more weight, the more blockrate. Also, the weight tells how much the attacking weapon ignores the blocking weapon's blockrate. Let's say a dagger attacking a blocking warhammer. This has almost none effect on the warhammer but if the warhammer attacks a blocking dagger, it will hurts a lot even though the attack was blocked.

I'm a level 20 female Woodelf RP'ing as an assassin and I love to backstab guards. :3

Comment: Welcome to [gaming.se]! A few tips for your post: Don't just say "the wiki", but name which wiki (often very popular games will end up with several!) and perhaps link to the top page as well. For more tips, tricks and rules, visit the [faq]! ;)

Comment: Upvoted for describing your character, it's important to remember we play games to have fun despite killjoys who will edit questions to make them purely mechanical :)

Comment: @aditya We edit out noise because it improves the quality of the site and the site wouldn't exist if we didn't have high standards. I'd downvote your comment if I could.

Comment: Well, you *can't* downvote my comment, @SevenSidedDie. Hopefully you'll learn to lighten up thanks to that reality.

Comment: Secondly, *what* "standards" am I treading upon when I playfully write my (related) character's description in a question about the weapons I use on said character in a Role Playing Game? It can be considered a little "ambient music", hardly noise. Jeez.

Comment: @aditya There's a reason there's no downvoting on comments—the same reason I'm not dictator of Arqade. :) It takes all kinds to make this place tick. People like you keep it light, people like me keep posts from turning into story time.

Comment: :brofist: keep doing good, man :)

Comment: I hope you meant that you roleplay a wood elf character.